# Python string to dict

Tags: python, dictionary, freeradius

I am working on a custom Freeradius Python module. I am getting below data in a variable as STRING type. How can I convert this to dictionary.

```
[
 ["Acct-Input-Octets", "47762756"],
 ["NAS-Port-Type", "Ethernet"],
 ["Acct-Session-Id", "\"8172fde7\""],
 ["Acct-Output-Gigawords", "0"],
 ["Service-Type", "Framed-User"],
 ["Acct-Unique-Session-Id", "\"f55597d3cc05fe3a\""],
 ["Called-Station-Id", "\"myhome\""],
 ["Acct-Authentic", "RADIUS"],
 ["Acct-Status-Type", "Interim-Update"],
 ["Acct-Output-Packets", "698213"],
 ["NAS-IP-Address", "192.168.100.100"],
 ["NAS-Port-Id", "\"vlan555\""],
 ["Acct-Output-Octets", "379021490"],
 ["Acct-Session-Time", "33900"],
 ["Calling-Station-Id", "\"A0:CC:DD:9F:F2:09\""],
 ["Framed-Protocol", "PPP"],
 ["User-Name", "\"testing\""],
 ["NAS-Identifier", "\"testing_radius\""],
 ["Event-Timestamp", "\"Sep  6 2014 02:09:40 PKT\""],
 ["Acct-Input-Gigawords", "0"],
 ["Framed-IP-Address", "172.16.100.100"],
 ["Acct-Input-Packets", "622069"],
 ["NAS-Port", "467422"],
 ["Acct-Delay-Time", "0"]
]
```

So for example,
I want to map below as one key vale

> ["Acct-Input-Octets", "7281436"]

So it should come out as

> data = { "Acct-Input-Octets" : 7281436 }

There are cases where there are escaped quotes like in

> ["NAS-Identifier", "\"testing_radius\""]

I am using CentOS 6.4 which comes with Python 2.6

Comment: Those escaped quotes are valid JSON escaped quotes; everything about your input is valid as JSON.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use the [`json` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html):

```
dict(json.loads(inputstring))
```

The `json.loads()` call converts the string to a Python list of lists. `dict()` takes the key-value pairs in that list and builds a dictionary from them.

Converting numeric values to integers is an extra step, but it can be integrated:

```
dict((k, int(v) if v.isdigit() else v) for k, v in json.loads(inputstring))
```

Demo:

```
>>> import json
>>> inputstring = r'''[["Acct-Input-Octets", "47762756"], ["NAS-Port-Type", "Ethernet"], ["Acct-Session-Id", "\"8172fde7\""], ["Acct-Output-Gigawords", "0"], ["Service-Type", "Framed-User"], ["Acct-Unique-Session-Id", "\"f55597d3cc05fe3a\""], ["Called-Station-Id", "\"myhome\""], ["Acct-Authentic", "RADIUS"], ["Acct-Status-Type", "Interim-Update"], ["Acct-Output-Packets", "698213"], ["NAS-IP-Address", "192.168.100.100"], ["NAS-Port-Id", "\"vlan555\""], ["Acct-Output-Octets", "379021490"], ["Acct-Session-Time", "33900"], ["Calling-Station-Id", "\"A0:CC:DD:9F:F2:09\""], ["Framed-Protocol", "PPP"], ["User-Name", "\"testing\""], ["NAS-Identifier", "\"testing_radius\""], ["Event-Timestamp", "\"Sep 6 2014 02:09:40 PKT\""], ["Acct-Input-Gigawords", "0"], ["Framed-IP-Address", "172.16.100.100"], ["Acct-Input-Packets", "622069"], ["NAS-Port", "467422"], ["Acct-Delay-Time", "0"]]'''
>>> dict(json.loads(inputstring))
{u'NAS-IP-Address': u'192.168.100.100', u'Acct-Status-Type': u'Interim-Update', u'Acct-Input-Packets': u'622069', u'NAS-Identifier': u'"testing_radius"', u'Acct-Session-Id': u'"8172fde7"', u'Acct-Input-Octets': u'47762756', u'NAS-Port-Type': u'Ethernet', u'Acct-Session-Time': u'33900', u'Service-Type': u'Framed-User', u'Acct-Output-Gigawords': u'0', u'Acct-Output-Octets': u'379021490', u'Acct-Delay-Time': u'0', u'Framed-Protocol': u'PPP', u'Acct-Authentic': u'RADIUS', u'Acct-Input-Gigawords': u'0', u'Calling-Station-Id': u'"A0:CC:DD:9F:F2:09"', u'NAS-Port': u'467422', u'Acct-Unique-Session-Id': u'"f55597d3cc05fe3a"', u'Event-Timestamp': u'"Sep 6 2014 02:09:40 PKT"', u'User-Name': u'"testing"', u'NAS-Port-Id': u'"vlan555"', u'Acct-Output-Packets': u'698213', u'Called-Station-Id': u'"myhome"', u'Framed-IP-Address': u'172.16.100.100'}
>>> pprint(_)
{u'Acct-Authentic': u'RADIUS',
 u'Acct-Delay-Time': u'0',
 u'Acct-Input-Gigawords': u'0',
 u'Acct-Input-Octets': u'47762756',
 u'Acct-Input-Packets': u'622069',
 u'Acct-Output-Gigawords': u'0',
 u'Acct-Output-Octets': u'379021490',
 u'Acct-Output-Packets': u'698213',
 u'Acct-Session-Id': u'"8172fde7"',
 u'Acct-Session-Time': u'33900',
 u'Acct-Status-Type': u'Interim-Update',
 u'Acct-Unique-Session-Id': u'"f55597d3cc05fe3a"',
 u'Called-Station-Id': u'"myhome"',
 u'Calling-Station-Id': u'"A0:CC:DD:9F:F2:09"',
 u'Event-Timestamp': u'"Sep 6 2014 02:09:40 PKT"',
 u'Framed-IP-Address': u'172.16.100.100',
 u'Framed-Protocol': u'PPP',
 u'NAS-IP-Address': u'192.168.100.100',
 u'NAS-Identifier': u'"testing_radius"',
 u'NAS-Port': u'467422',
 u'NAS-Port-Id': u'"vlan555"',
 u'NAS-Port-Type': u'Ethernet',
 u'Service-Type': u'Framed-User',
 u'User-Name': u'"testing"'}
>>> dict((k, int(v) if v.isdigit() else v) for k, v in json.loads(inputstring))
{u'NAS-IP-Address': u'192.168.100.100', u'Acct-Status-Type': u'Interim-Update', u'Acct-Input-Packets': 622069, u'NAS-Identifier': u'"testing_radius"', u'Acct-Session-Id': u'"8172fde7"', u'Acct-Input-Octets': 47762756, u'NAS-Port-Type': u'Ethernet', u'Acct-Session-Time': 33900, u'Service-Type': u'Framed-User', u'Acct-Output-Gigawords': 0, u'Acct-Output-Octets': 379021490, u'Acct-Delay-Time': 0, u'Framed-Protocol': u'PPP', u'Acct-Authentic': u'RADIUS', u'Acct-Input-Gigawords': 0, u'Calling-Station-Id': u'"A0:CC:DD:9F:F2:09"', u'NAS-Port': 467422, u'Acct-Unique-Session-Id': u'"f55597d3cc05fe3a"', u'Event-Timestamp': u'"Sep 6 2014 02:09:40 PKT"', u'User-Name': u'"testing"', u'NAS-Port-Id': u'"vlan555"', u'Acct-Output-Packets': 698213, u'Called-Station-Id': u'"myhome"', u'Framed-IP-Address': u'172.16.100.100'}
>>> pprint(_)
{u'Acct-Authentic': u'RADIUS',
 u'Acct-Delay-Time': 0,
 u'Acct-Input-Gigawords': 0,
 u'Acct-Input-Octets': 47762756,
 u'Acct-Input-Packets': 622069,
 u'Acct-Output-Gigawords': 0,
 u'Acct-Output-Octets': 379021490,
 u'Acct-Output-Packets': 698213,
 u'Acct-Session-Id': u'"8172fde7"',
 u'Acct-Session-Time': 33900,
 u'Acct-Status-Type': u'Interim-Update',
 u'Acct-Unique-Session-Id': u'"f55597d3cc05fe3a"',
 u'Called-Station-Id': u'"myhome"',
 u'Calling-Station-Id': u'"A0:CC:DD:9F:F2:09"',
 u'Event-Timestamp': u'"Sep 6 2014 02:09:40 PKT"',
 u'Framed-IP-Address': u'172.16.100.100',
 u'Framed-Protocol': u'PPP',
 u'NAS-IP-Address': u'192.168.100.100',
 u'NAS-Identifier': u'"testing_radius"',
 u'NAS-Port': 467422,
 u'NAS-Port-Id': u'"vlan555"',
 u'NAS-Port-Type': u'Ethernet',
 u'Service-Type': u'Framed-User',
 u'User-Name': u'"testing"'}
```

Comment: I tried that just now and got "ValueError: Expecting , delimiter: line 1 column 89 (char 89)"

Comment: It might be better to make it clear that there are two steps here: first using the `json` module to parse the string into a list of key-value lists, and then calling `dict` to convert any sequence of 2-sequences into a dictionary.

Comment: @MudasirMirza: Then you've screwed up the string somehow before this step. If I take Martijn's code (notice the `r` for "raw string literal"), or paste your input into a text file and read it in, it's valid JSON. But if I just paste your input into Python source without using a raw string literal, then of course it isn't, because you end up with `""` instead of `"\"` all over the place.

Comment: I upvoted this answer but it doesn't solve the whole problem. The incoming json has decimal strings like `["Acct-Input-Octets", "7281436"]` that need to be converted to ints like `{ "Acct-Input-Octets" : 7281436 }`. It would be great if the thing that generated the json did things right in the first place, but the values that need to be converted to int need to be flagged and handled somehow.

Comment: @tdelaney: added that too.

Comment: The issue is that Freeradius Python module calls a functions with arguments "accounting(p)" and "p" has all the data. I don't know how to assign "raw string literal" to this "p" variable"

Comment: @MudasirMirza: then add the output of `repr(p)` to your question. Or is it the *return value* of `accounting(p)` you are trying to interpret? Then give us `repr(accounting(p))`.

Comment: For Python 3.5 (assuming [PEP 463](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0463/) makes it in time), I might use `int(v) except ValueError: v` instead of `int(v) if v.isdigit() else v`. But for 3.4 or earlier, the small benefit of EAFP definitely doesn't outweigh the cost of turning that trivial expression into a 4-line statement.

Comment: @abarnert: The percentage of integer values is not really that high; and since the sample doesn't contain any values with minus signs or whitespace I am not curtain that is worth it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Not for performance (it's unlikely to matter either way), or even really robustness (although that's more likely to come up), just that I think it's clearer to say "turn anything into an integer that makes sense" than "turn anything into an integer if it's made of digits".

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> dict(json.loads(r'''[["Acct-Input-Octets", "47762756"], ["NAS-Port-Type", "Ethernet"], ["Acct-Session-Id", "\"8172fde7\""], ["Acct-Output-Gigawords", "0"], ["Service-Type", "Framed-User"], ["Acct-Unique-Session-Id", "\"f55597d3cc05fe3a\""], ["Called-Station-Id", "\"myhome\""], ["Acct-Authentic", "RADIUS"], ["Acct-Status-Type", "Interim-Update"], ["Acct-Output-Packets", "698213"], ["NAS-IP-Address", "192.168.100.100"], ["NAS-Port-Id", "\"vlan555\""], ["Acct-Output-Octets", "379021490"], ["Acct-Session-Time", "33900"], ["Calling-Station-Id", "\"A0:CC:DD:9F:F2:09\""], ["Framed-Protocol", "PPP"], ["User-Name", "\"testing\""], ["NAS-Identifier", "\"testing_radius\""], ["Event-Timestamp", "\"Sep 6 2014 02:09:40 PKT\""], ["Acct-Input-Gigawords", "0"], ["Framed-IP-Address", "172.16.100.100"], ["Acct-Input-Packets", "622069"], ["NAS-Port", "467422"], ["Acct-Delay-Time", "0"]]'''))
{u'NAS-IP-Address': u'192.168.100.100', u'Acct-Status-Type': u'Interim-Update', u'Acct-Input-Packets': u'622069', u'NAS-Identifier': u'"testing_radius"', u'Acct-Session-Id': u'"8172fde7"', u'Acct-Input-Octets': u'47762756', u'NAS-Port-Type': u'Ethernet', u'Acct-Session-Time': u'33900', u'Service-Type': u'Framed-User', u'Acct-Output-Gigawords': u'0', u'Acct-Output-Octets': u'379021490', u'Acct-Delay-Time': u'0', u'Framed-Protocol': u'PPP', u'Acct-Authentic': u'RADIUS', u'Acct-Input-Gigawords': u'0', u'Calling-Station-Id': u'"A0:CC:DD:9F:F2:09"', u'NAS-Port': u'467422', u'Acct-Unique-Session-Id': u'"f55597d3cc05fe3a"', u'Event-Timestamp': u'"Sep 6 2014 02:09:40 PKT"', u'User-Name': u'"testing"', u'NAS-Port-Id': u'"vlan555"', u'Acct-Output-Packets': u'698213', u'Called-Station-Id': u'"myhome"', u'Framed-IP-Address': u'172.16.100.100'}
```